# Netbeans 7.1 SVN Lock Feature

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans-7.1

I have just installed Netbeans 7.1, mainly for the SVN lock feature.

I was disappointed to find that I could not create a keyboard shortcut for the lock feature from Tools->Options->Keymap (if it can be done great, tell me how please).

I have noticed then when you open a file you get a sub-toolbar for that file (image below).

[image]

I would be good if there is a way to add a shortcut to this toolbar to lock the file. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

- press 'Alt' + 'm'
- release 'm' (keep 'Alt' pressed)
- press 'l'  ('L')
- release all keys